# pass param as an array instead of string in rails get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to trigger the url where I am passing parameters in the array format

`http://localhost:3000/abc/23?field_selectors=['surname', 'firstname']`

when I try to get this params it comes in string like

`[2] pry(#<PersonController>)> params[:field_selectors]
=> "['surname', 'firstname']"`

I tried to remove the `""` from both the ends but it again return a string.

`"['surname', 'firstname']".chomp('"').reverse.chomp('"').reverse`

The above implementation is very idiotic but I tried

Now I am confused how can I covert the given string into an array or how can i get the params directly as an array.

Comment: have you tried params[:field_selectors].to_a ?

Comment: yup @ThorTL67, but it didnt work

Comment: Isn't it better to pass string to params first like 'surname,firstname ' and then convert it into array that you wanted to?

Comment: I dont think thats a better idea, because then for everything like hash ,array i need to convert it into string.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have both spaces and unsafe ('[ ]') characters in your URL string. Why not output a traditional query string? `/url?surname=something&firstname=something`

Comment: try `http://localhost:3000/abc/23?field_selectors[]=surname&field_selectors[]=firstname`

Comment: Then you need to parse string. Like trim the first and last two chars and split it with comma char. With this you can get that array you want. But this is not a good way to do it in my opinion. This might work  `"['surname', 'firstname']"[1..-2].tr('\'','').split(',')`

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay, Perfect man, just what I am looking for ...:-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want params to register as an array to Rails' param parsing code, append `[]` to the end of the param:

```
http://localhost:3000/abc/23?field_selectors[]=surname&field_selectors[]=firstname
```

`params[:field_selectors]` will then automatically be parsed as an array of strings.